# problems creating SAAJ object model

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui, html-escape-characters, saaj

i tried to send a SOAP request in jquery to third party but always got this error:

`<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Problems creating SAAJ object model</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

the way i did it is to pass couple of tokens to another function ,which create SOAP request based on those token. one of the token is a Html string like this:

```
<tr><td width="2" bgcolor="#ffffff"><\/td><td width="1" bgcolor="#d8dbe3"><\/td><td width="2" bgcolor="#ffffff"><\/td><td width="15" bgcolor="#f5f6f8"><\/td><td width="535" bgcolor="#f5f6f8"><table width="535" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#f5f6f8"><tr><td width="80"><table width="80" height="96" bgcolor="#999999" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center"><tr><td width="80" height="1" colspan="3"><\/td><\/tr><tr><td width="1" bgcolor="#999999"><\/td>....
```

whenever i added this token, the SOAP request failed. I tried to escaped this html string token, SOAP request succeeded but the whole string messed up with all the escaped characters and third party need this html string to render template, so i cannot sent the escaped version anyway. is there any way i can safely pass the html string without crashing the request?

Answer (score 8):

Error "Problems creating SAAJ object model" usually occurs when **soap-request cannot be parsed on the server side**.
In the log-file on the server you can see something like

```
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '>' (code 62) (expected a name start character)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [18,6]
```

You pass html tags to the soap envelope, so **problems can be with escaping html-tags**. It's a good practice to pass BASE64 string within soap-request for such kind of data

Comment: Please give an example or reference how to pass BASE64 string within soap request

Answer (score 0):

Please add a header like tihs "Content-type text/xml;charset=utf-8".